# Auto move media file to cloud

Tags: plugins, uploads, media, cloud

I have very little space to host my WordPress website. That is why I want all my media files are stored in the cloud like dropbox, google drive etc.

For example, if a user wants to upload an image from the front-end using the common upload file button, then the image file is automatically stored directly to the cloud.

or

the image file will first stored in the upload folder then automatically moved into the cloud. So then my upload folder will always empty in order to save my very little space.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WP Offload S3](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/) is pretty much the best WP -> Amazon s3 plugin out there

Comment: Yes it works! thx..

Comment: Yes it works! thx..

Comment: Your welcome!  If this answered your question, be sure to accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

A free (and [open source](https://github.com/wpCloud/wp-stateless)) option is [Stateless](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-stateless/), it's working with Google cloud storage.